# resizing stage to fit photo

Tags: flash, actionscript

I want to create an application which loads pictures of diferent sizes like 720x800 1600x1000 2200x2000 and I want to show those pictures. Want I want is to load pictures with different sizes in a window which fits half my browser window(which i think can be done with javascript and html), and to load the whole quality of all pictures and not try to scale them down to fit them in a smaller window. This means a browser on a bigger screen shows more pixels and the whole quality of bigger pictures. What I think I need is to scale movieclips but also the stage. The second I don't know how to do during execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You rarely want the stage to scale when you are writing an application for which you do not know the dimensions at author-time (and which hence requires a "liquid" layout.) When the stage scales, that scale needs to be accounted for in all transformations, unless you want all your content to scale too. Hence, what most people usually do is disable stage scaling altogether, and instead align the display list to the upper left corner of the embed window. This can be done using ActionSCript like so:

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

This should be all that you need to do to make your loaded images show up in their 1:1 size, regardless of the embed window's dimensions, and be cropped when the window is too small.

Comment: I don't know if this helps me, what I mean is I have two pictures which I put in two movieclips that are next to eachother with which I perform some actions. So when I have two pictures 1000x1000 and 720x1000 I would want my stage to be 1720x1000 like I think youtube does , althought I am not sure, when one switches from 480p to 720p, I think it changes stage resolution.

Comment: That's a JavaScript changing the width and height of the embed/object element. You'll still need to set the properties as in my answer above though.